# axios POST request is not sent

Tags: node.js

Faced such a problem and can no longer solve it 2 days, please help.
There is a server on the nodejs:

index.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const keys = require("./config/keys");
const app = require("./app");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

mongoose
  .connect(keys.MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
    console.log("Connected to" + " MongoDB");
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const passport = require("passport");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const restaurantRoutes = require("./routes/restaurant");

const app = express();

app.use(passport.initialize());
require("./middleware/passport")(passport);

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/restaurant", restaurantRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

Nested Routes:

```
router.get(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  controller.getAll
);

router.get(
  "/:id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  controller.getById
);

router.post(
  "/create",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  upload.single("image"),
  controller.create
);

router.patch(
  "/update",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  upload.single("image"),
  controller.update
);

router.delete(
  "/:id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  controller.delete
);
```

There is a request from the front:

```
export function createNewRestaurant(restaurant, token) {
  return {
    type: CREATE_NEW_RESTAURANT,
    payload: axios({
      type: "POST",
      url: "api/restaurant/create",
      headers: {
        Authorization: token,
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(restaurant),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        // return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log({ error });
        // return error.response.data;
      }),
  };
}
```

The problem is that POST doesn't even get from the server ...
There is no mention of it in the server console

If you remove the line from package.json client

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"
```

and write in the request

```
url: "http://localhost:3001/api/restaurant/create",
```

then in the server console we will see the OPTIONS request

```
OPTIONS /api/restaurant/create 204 0.135 ms - 0
```

I understand that the case is CORS, but I have it installed and in theory should work it all out, but how does this happen?
In postman, the request goes fine
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the dev. console in the browser saying? What's the part of the code that's console logging the request from the client?

Comment: The fact of the matter is that nothing comes from the server to the browser at all. I only see request headers there

Comment: Man. It's almost impossible that the dev. console in the browser returns absolutely nothing in this case. Can we have a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, no propblem)

Comment: I didn't see `type: "POST"` in axios docs. Did you try `method: "POST"` instead?

Comment: I mean the console tab, not the network tab @RomanAdigezalov

Comment: Saeed.Ataee!! Man! You just saved me from losing my mind)) I spent two days in the kidneys answer! And he was in a commonplace mistake!